Apache airflow docker fails to run on desktop
I am on Windows laptop and a desktop
On both these machines I installed docker desktop
Then I use the docker file and docker compose which are sharedhere
docker-compose.yaml : docker-compose
dockerfile: dockerfile
Things work fine on laptop but on desktop i see that i get errors like
 => ERROR [airflow-init 3/8] RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install
-y                                                                                                                                   0.3s
------
 > [airflow-init 3/8] RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y:
------ failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -o pipefail -o errexit -o nounset -o nolog -c apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y" did 
not complete successfully:
 unable to find user root: no matching entries in passwd file

Why is that on laptop root was configured and not on desktop .
I have tried to create root user on desktop docker file but nothing helps
